# SQL: Distinct record on certain condition

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm using Redshift and I have table like this:

***<Table A***

[image]

I want query distinct record for Seq1& Seq2 which contain both 1111 and 2222 in ProductCode:

***<Desired Result***

[image]

I have tried the following query but of course not worked as I needed

```
SELECT DISTINCT Seq1, Seq2
FROM A
WHERE ProductCode IN (1111,2222)
```

***<Result(NG)***

[image]

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below -

```
SELECT  Seq1, Seq2
FROM A
WHERE ProductCode IN (1111,2222)
group by Seq1, Seq2
having count(distinct productcode)=2
```